# Learn Python the Hard Way Ex 48

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to complete Learn Python the Hard Way exercise 48 and when I'm testing with nosetests, to my dismay, I get KeyError on test_numbers() and test_errors(). Listed here is my code that I use(code primarily based off DairyLee's solution):

```
lexicon = {}
for directions in ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'down', 
                   'up', 'left', 'right', 'back']:
    lexicon.update({directions: 'direction'})
for verbs in ['go', 'stop', 'kill', 'eat']:
    lexicon.update({verbs: 'verb'})
for stops in ['the', 'in', 'of', 'from', 'at', 'it']:
    lexicon.update({stops: 'stop'})
for nouns in ['door', 'bear', 'princess', 'cabinet']:
    lexicon.update({nouns: 'noun'})

stuff = raw_input('> ')
words = stuff.lower().split()

def scan(sentance):
    words = sentance.lower().split()
    pairs = []
    for word in words:
        if lexicon[word] == 'direction':
            pairs.append(('direction', word))
        elif lexicon[word] == 'verb':
            pairs.append(('verb', word))
        elif lexicon[word] == 'noun':
            pairs.append(('noun', word))
        elif lexicon[word] == 'stop':
            pairs.append(('stop', word))
        elif lexicon[word] == 'noun':
            pairs.append(('noun', word))
        elif convert_number(word) != None:
            pairs.append(('number', convert_number(word)))
        else:
            pairs.append(('error', word))
    return pairs

def convert_number(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

And here is the page. http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex48.html which contains the relevant part of the test:

```
def test_numbers():
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("1234"), [('number', 1234)])
    result = lexicon.scan("3 91234")
    assert_equal(result, [('number', 3),
                          ('number', 91234)])


def test_errors():
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("ASDFADFASDF"), [('error', 'ASDFADFASDF')])
    result = lexicon.scan("bear IAS princess")
    assert_equal(result, [('noun', 'bear'),
                          ('error', 'IAS'),
                          ('noun', 'princess')])
```

From my understanding it appears that the test won't continue as long as the key is not within the lexicon dictionary which is weird as I've put a else statement right at the end of the for loop. Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: the whole point of doing a tutorial is to try and figure this type of stuff out for yourself... and I'm not even sure this is a question

Comment: I don't see `test_numbers()` or `test_errors()` anywhere in your code. However, I do see `try:enter code here`.

Comment: @konkked I don't understand why this code wouldn't work. Should I post my results from powershell as well?

Comment: @A.J. I've updated OP. For some reason 'enter code here' was added.

Comment: I can't spot what the error is, but I do know you could basically reduce your scan function to one line by doing `return [(lexicon[word], word) for word in sentence.lower().split()]`.

Comment: @Asad That works out actually. A whole lot more useful than my solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Reginsmal Actually, that ignores numbers. And realizing this exposed the error in your code as well. I think you need to move your number branch to the top of your switch.

Comment: @Asasd True. I instead put it inside a try statement and find if it's number or not defined in keyerror.

Comment: @Reginsmal So everything is working now? If so, please post your working code as an answer to this question and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my final developed answer. Thank you Asad for the shortcut.

```
lexicon = {}
for directions in ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'down', 
                   'up', 'left', 'right', 'back']:
    lexicon.update({directions: 'direction'})
for verbs in ['go', 'stop', 'kill', 'eat']:
    lexicon.update({verbs: 'verb'})
for stops in ['the', 'in', 'of', 'from', 'at', 'it']:
    lexicon.update({stops: 'stop'})
for nouns in ['door', 'bear', 'princess', 'cabinet']:
    lexicon.update({nouns: 'noun'})



stuff = raw_input('> ')
words = stuff.lower().split()

def scan(sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    pairs = []
    for word in words:
        try:
            k = word.lower()
            pairs.append((lexicon[k], word))
        except KeyError:
            if convert_number(word) != None:
                 pairs.append(('number', int(word)))
            else:
                pairs.append(('error', word))
    return pairs

def convert_number(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def scan(sentence):
  words = sentence.split()
  v = ["go","kill","eat","stop"]
  dw ["north","south","east","west","down","up","left","right","back"]
  sw = ["the","in","of","from","at","it"]
  n = ["door","bear","princess","cabinet"]
  sent = []
  for i in words:
      if i in v:
          result = ('verb', i)
          sent.append(result)
      elif i in dw:
          result = ('direction', i)
          sent.append(result)
      elif i in sw:
          result = ('stop', i)
          sent.append(result)
      elif i in n:
          result = ('noun', i)
          sent.append(result)
      elif i.isdigit() and len(i)<=9:
          result = ('number', int(i))``
          sent.append(result)
      else:
          result = ('error', i)
          sent.append(result)
  return sent
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. When answering the question, please provide a short explanation of the issue and how your code resolves it, rather than just pasting the code.